# Set Default paging null

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-web

I use spring boot 2

Seem like spring boot put a default value for pageable, if user put nothing... I would like to get null or nothing...

```
@GetMapping(value = "networks")
public ResponseEntity<Page<Networks>> getNetworks(@RequestParam(required = false) String search, Pageable page) {

}
```

So I tried to put `@requestparam` with `required=false`:

```
@GetMapping(value = "networks")
public ResponseEntity<Page<Networks>> getNetworks(@RequestParam(required = false) String search, @RequestParam(required = false) Pageable page) {

}
```

but if user type

http://localhost:8080/networks?search=&page=0&size=10&sort=id%2Casc 50

I get

> "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable': no matching editors or
>   conversion strategy found",   "path" : "/

If user type 
http://localhost:8080/networks 
that work

Comment: Sort part consists of direction + sortProperty. Direction is an enum with uppercase values.
`public static enum Direction { ASC, DESC; }`. Try to change URL ending to `&sort=id&direction=ASC`